# What R package can I use to incorporate inverse probability weights (to adjust for survey design & interwave attrition) into a GEE model?

Tags: r, regression

I am analyzing a longitudinal dataset (using R) that has provided inverse probability weights to adjust for initial sampling methods (two-stage clustered) and subsequent differential interwave attrition aiming to achieve a study population that is representative of the source population.

I want to run unweighted and weighted GEE models (GEE models chosen due to the clustering of participants in classrooms) and I have a binary outcome (assessed at a single time point i.e. no repeated measures).

I have two issues:

`geeglm()` won't accept the outcome coded as a factor (coded with two levels: No/Yes) even though `family = "binomial"`. It's a complete case analysis so NAs are excluded from the data frame. Here is the structure of my model:

```
mod <- geeglm(outcome ~ predictor1 + predictor2, data=complete_df, family = "binomial", id=cluster_id, corstr = "exchangeable")
```

Here is the error message:

```
error in lm.fit(zsca, qlf(pr2), offset= soffset : NA/NaNInf in 'y' "in addition: warning message: 1. In model response(mf, "numeric") : using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored 2. In ops.factor(y, mu) : '-' not meaningful for factors
```

However, my (unweighted) GEE model runs without an error message with the outcome as an integer (0/1). Does anyone know why this might be? Is it not possible to use a factor outcome in a binomial GEE?

What R package will allow me to appropriately incorporate my weights into a GEE model? I tried geeglm() using the argument weights = but I get this error message:

```
Warning message: in eval(family$initialize): non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
```

I am assuming that this may be arising from how the weights (numeric) are interacting with my integer outcome. Despite the error message, the results of the weighted GEE model print out and look relatively reasonable. When I looked through the `geepack` manual, the weights argument is from `glm()` and specifies that "for a binomial glm prior weights are used to give the number of trials when the response is the proportion of successes” so I am not sure if this is appropriate for my analysis?

I have read papers using similar datasets that have managed to apply this type of weights in a GEE model but using different software so I am unsure how to proceed.